# How to build a sentence classifier with tensorflow, that has two sub bi-lstms one for sentence embedding and other for sentence classification?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow

I want to build a model that takes a document, creates sentence embedding for each sentence using a bi-LSTM, then use the sequence of sentences embedding as input to another bi-LSTM that outputs a probability for each sentence to be a topic shift boundary. I have difficulty building the model, as I never did any custom training before, I am used to considering the whole words as one sequence. Any hints ?